# Java Memory Model and happen before relationship

Tags: java

In the following execution,

T1

l1.lock

a.write

l1.unlock


          T2

          l2.lock

          a.read

          l2.unlock

can a in T2 read the new value written in T1?

I have two conflicting conclusions:

1. The unlock of l1 in T1 will flush the new value of a into main memory and the lock of l2 in T2 will force T2 to update the cache and a in T2 can get the new value of a.
2. Since l1 and l2 are different locks, the write of a in T1 do not have a happen before relationship with the read of a in T2. Thus, a in T2 can not be guarantteed to read the new value.

I have no idea which one is correct. Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this code executing sychronously (in order in same method)?

Comment: Well, 2. is correct; there is no guarantee that "T2 will update the cache" at all. When entering a monitor, the only guarantee is that all instructions before the monitor are guaranteed to be executed before the monitor is entered.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Java lanuguage specification..

1) An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on **the same monitor**.

2) All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join() on that thread.

So, its pretty clear that the Answer is 2. if the two thread have join between them then answer is 1.

please refer to JLS for more details..